# Adding data to Firestore dynamically

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to add a dynamic amount of strings to Firestore?

This is my code:

I use a string array called names.

```swift
let newDoc = ref.collection("Docs").document()
for i in 0 ..< names.count{
    newDoc.setData(["\(i)" : names[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you probably don't want to be calling `setData` repetitively like that. Instead, you can translate `names` into a `Dictionary<String,String>` and then just call `setData` once:

```
let names = [String]()
let dictVersion = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: names.enumerated().map { index, value in
   return ("\(index)",value)
})
let newDoc = ref.collection("Docs").document()
newDoc.setData(dictVersion)
```